# Resizing west side of JFrame java

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

I'm currently trying to implement resizing of my window made with an undecorated `JFrame` using MouseListeners. Here's an example of my implementation of resizing the east side of the JFrame.

`sizeX` and `sizeY` is the frame's current size taken from the initialization part of the program. `bg` is the only element on my content pane. I used `frame.pack()`.

```
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        if((sizeX - 2) <= e.getX()){
            changeCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR), true);
        }else{
            changeCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR), false);
        }

        printInfo("Moved", e);
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        if(sizeX < e.getX() ||
                sizeX > e.getX()){
            resizeXE(e);
        }
        printInfo("Dragged", e);
    }
    void changeCursor(Cursor cursor, boolean resize){
        if(resize){
            resizeFlag = true;
        }else{
            resizeFlag = false;
        }
        bg.setCursor(cursor);
    }
    void resizeXE(MouseEvent e){
        if(resizeFlag){
            sizeX = e.getX();
            ((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, bg)).setSize(
                    sizeX, sizeY);
        }
    }
```

I need help trying to implement resizing of the west side. I believe if I figure this out I'll probably won't need help on the north and south sides.

As you can see I'm trying to resize using the `setSize()` method. However I don't see how I can use that on the west side. Any suggestions for alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you can see I'm trying to resize using the setSize() method.

When you resize on the west you need to use:

1. setLocation(...) - because the edge of the frame moves to a new place
2. setSize(...) - because the size also increases.

Comment: Makes sense. I was actually avoiding to do this but I'll try this now.

Comment: I've finished implementing it but it's too.. twitchy. Compared to the west, the east resizing is much smoother. This is obviously caused by `setLocation`. Is it possible to make it resize cleaner?

Comment: @user2280704, See [Resizing Components](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) for my implementation. It will be more complicated than yours because it supports other features like snapping, but it may give you some ideas if you look at the code closely.